# SKScene returns nil when transition method is called

Tags: swift, skscene

In my little Xcode Project I am trying to transition scenes by when my SKLabelNode is touched it presents the next scene. For some reason in my scene transition method it makes me store it as an optional. And the optional returns false. My file names are correct and no grammatical errors in the references would be causing the problem here is my code. When I click my SKLabelNode my ios platform that is running it on recognizes the touch then the app crashes, in console saying that an optional value returned nil. How could I resolve this problem? Thanks

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

let next = SKScene(fileNamed: "nextScene")

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {


    let backgroundimage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ipbg")
    backgroundimage.size = CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
    backgroundimage.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2, y: self.frame.size.height / 2)
    addChild(backgroundimage)

    let playButton = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "")
    playButton.name = "play"
    playButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2, y: self.frame.size.height / 2 + 100)
    playButton.text = "Play"

    let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(2)
    let run = SKAction.runBlock({


        let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(4)))

        switch(randomNumber){

        case (0):

            playButton.fontColor = UIColor.blueColor()

        case 1:

            playButton.fontColor = UIColor.yellowColor()

        case 2:

            playButton.fontColor = UIColor.purpleColor()

        case 3:

            playButton.fontColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

        default: print("default")


        }

    })

    addChild(playButton)
    var repeatActionForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([wait, run]))
    runAction(repeatActionForever)
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    let trans = SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(1)
    let touch = touches.first! as UITouch
    let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
    let touchedNode = nodeAtPoint(touchLocation)

    if touchedNode.name == "play"{


        scene!.view?.presentScene(next!, transition: trans)

        }

    }
}

func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}
```

Comment: Please indicate the line of code where the app does crash. And also add the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted does not compile so it's hard to find the error.

However I would try replacing the `touchesBegan` method with the following

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    let trans = SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(1)
    let touch = touches.first! as UITouch
    let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
    let touchedNode = nodeAtPoint(touchLocation)

    if touchedNode.name == "play"{
        guard let nextScene = SKScene(fileNamed: "nextScene")
            else { fatalError("Could not load nextScene") }
        self.view?.presentScene(nextScene, transition: trans)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to store the scene as a property just add it in the touches began method.

Also you should create the corresponding swift file and class for each scene instead of trying to initialising a .sks file with a generic SKScene object. The line ...(fileNamed: "nextScene") looks for an .sks file (Xcode visual level editor file), if you haven't created one your property will be nil.

To make it work do this:

First make sure you created a .sks file called NextScene (right click a file in your project -> New -> Resource -> SpriteKit Scene)

Secondly create a new swift file and create a new class called NextScene

```
 class NextScene: SKScene { 

 }
```

Than the loading code in your touches label function would look like this.

```
  override func touchesBegan... {
       ...

       if let nextScene = NextScene(fileNamed: "NextScene") //actually init the corresponding class with the corresponding .sks file
       /// scene presenting code
      }

   }
```

As you mentioned your scene property returns an optional because the fileNamed (.sks file) you specified might not exists, so check it is there. In general its better practice to safely unwrap like I do above or the default loading code in GameViewController does, instead of just force unwrapping with a ! .

If you don't use the visual level editor than just create your scene class and ignore creating the .sks file and load your scene like so

```
 let nextScene = NextScene(size: self.size) // use current scene size
  /// scene presenting code
```

Note: Your file names should start with capital letters